# Fade Object Inside Transparent Game Object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two cylinders in my scene.  The outer cylinder (Cylinder A) has planes facing the outside and planes facing the inside to represent glass.

Cylinder A has a standard shader on it, set to transparent mode, it has an albedo Alpha of 143.  It has also a shininess to it represented by it's smoothness and this is set to 1.

Cylinder B has a Standard Shader on it,  set to transparent mode, It has an albedo alpha that animates from 255 to 0 over a short period of time.  It has a Normal map set to 0.3 and no smoothness.

Here is an image to act as a guide.

[image]

The problem involves the Cylinder B not 'playing ball'.  It should be inside Cylinder A - and would look right if Cylinder A's shininess was visible to the viewer.

I have provided a second example where Cylinder B is in Opaque mode (Standard Shader).  It looks right - except it cannot animate a fade.[image]

I have looked into this.  From what I have experienced - Cutout Mode will either be Transparent or Opaque, nothing in between.  Fade mode has the same effect.

I can see that this has to do with Z Ordering and that ZWriting may be the way to fix this.  I am unfamiliar with it's placement within shaders or if it will work while an animation fades out the alpha of Cylinder B and wondering can anyone point me in the right direction for a further understanding.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the transparent render queue where nothing works the way you want it to because solving the sorting order question is *really freaking hard* and you've fallen into one of the places where existing implementations don't solve it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome :)  I came across a post like this one which may be a workaround for some.  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1012048/how-do-i-change-the-render-queue.html  It involves customing how things are rendered in order.  I am still havbing artifacts appear up throughout (due to some pieces of the model beyond the tubes encapsulating them - however I believe I may be able to split these and set their render queue up appropriately.  Let's see and I'll share the results if nothing else comes up.

Comment: That's pretty much all you can do: fiddle with the rendering order manually.